# Professionally and politely dealing with an untenable situation in contract work

Tags: professionalism, contracts, unprofessional-behavior

Preface: I am new to engineering after thirteen years in academia, and I've noticed the standards for professional and polite are very different between the two situations, so I'm not sure academic standards apply here.

I signed a contract to work on a project which has now gone on more than twice as long as it was contracted to last. A variety of things could be the culprit, so the specific reasons don't matter here except for to say that in my well-documented opinion, the project is not able to be finished. The general issues include serious communication problems that I am unable to resolve; constant revision of goals and requirements; requirements that are not able to be completed as written; the refusal to comply with and/or use the tools, standards, and/or methods in the underlying architecture chosen for the project, causing me to need to constantly customize, override, and/or rewrite fundamental classes and/or methods; mass deletion of my work without explanation and occasionally without notification of any kind; my own inexperience; and what I am going to sum up as a conflict of personalities.

I assume I have to stay because I signed a contract, but I do not believe the contract will ever be finished, nor have my requests for prioritized lists of tasks and/or feedback on how to get the project finished been answered.

The rest of my pay for the contract is being held until the project manager is satisfied with my work, which appears highly unlikely to occur, and the tone and commentary in the feedback I've been given on my work and/or requests for clarification is demoralizing. I'm not sure the tone and comments are entirely intentional, but the effect is unpleasant enough without intent.

Under those conditions, what can I do to politely, professionally handle the situation?

My preferred goal here would be to leave, but I don't believe that's an option, so I would be interested in advice on how to behave as professionally as possible given the situation and, if at all possible, finish the project so that I am not abandoning it. I have and am extensively documenting interactions, changes, revisions to the goals, and/or all communication.

My request for a prioritized list finally got added today, after I wrote the question.

The contract is in the US.

A concise summary of this learning experience, as per reading the comments:

**1. Next time, I'll do a whole lot more detailed negotiation up front.**

**2. Scope changes will require renegotiation.**

**3. I'm insisting on explicit clauses for conditions under which I can terminate work.**

Comment: Do you still have the contract, what does the contract say? Look to see what the exact terms were for your employment and payment and if any of them are different to now, make that known to the company. You need to read your contract to know what you signed up for!

Comment: I read it before I signed it, yes. I am liable for delivery within a window we are currently outside. The given reasons are consistently stated to be my fault by the project manager.

Comment: What does it say about if the window is not met? What are the extension requirements?

Comment: None were stipulated in the contract. The emails I've received indicated that the client is willing to wait. I should state that I have an extensive email trail and/or documentation, so if it becomes a legal issue, I have fairly good ground to stand on.

Comment: If none were stipulated, it sounds like you're on uneven ground now, does the contract say it only ends when the product is delivered or when the time frame ends? If you're having real issues, I would suggest talking to somebody from a law background and see what's possible. If you do wish to carry on, you will most likely have to negotiate a new contract, to cover yourself and the place you're working for

Comment: Welcome back @wormwood. Keep in mind that for this site you should specify your goal, i.e. what you're trying to accomplish. In this case that could be completing the project, walking away professionally, mitigating fallout when it all goes wrong, arguing to receive your final pay etc. What are you trying to do? Aside from that: is this a flat-fee contract or are you paid for hours billed? Since you're also talking about contracts, specifying the country/state would also be useful.

Comment: The contract ends when the product is delivered. I would prefer not to go legal if I don't have to.

Comment: Being forced to work on a project with no pay entitled to that work? Sounds like a very bad and dodgy contract to me, does the contract have clauses in to say how you can break off from the work?

Comment: The pay is set for performance goals. The work is on a contract, not as a paid regular position.

Comment: I should say, too, that the project should have been deliverable within the time frame specified, and the conditions I was told I would be working under would have allowed it to be done quickly. Unfortunately, those conditions ceased to exist shortly after the work started.

Comment: Were the conditions of work included in the contract?

Comment: Sadly, no. They were a verbal agreement.

Comment: Any witnesses to that agreement? Recording of the conversation?

Comment: And again, no. My previous experience with contract work was in another field, in which this particular set of circumstances would never have occurred, so I was not aware I would need to get that in writing.

Comment: What timeframe are we talking here? Weeks, months, years? Also, as a general note, it's indeed a best practice here to [edit] new information into the original post but you don't need to put it after "Edit:" marks. It's fine to just update/rewrite the original text so it flows naturally. People who saw previous versions of your question can view the edit history if they want to see what changed.

Comment: As for the question, it all sounds like a typical failed project with scope creep, lack of clarity on features/specs, mismanagement and no change management. The typical advice is to take that as an expensive but necessary lesson in contracting work and to take steps to avoid this in the future. Since you believe the project is doomed beyond recovery you need to find a way to extract yourself and that probably becomes a legal question if you did sign a contract. At this point you're unlikely to get a good reference or future work from them anyway and you need to find a new gig.

Comment: All right, I'll remove the edit tag and won't use it next time. I will be treating this like a learning experience. Might as well get as much value as possible from the experience. Thank you.

Comment: I don't wish to establish a pattern of failure to finish projects. The quality of my work and reputation are important to me. I also don't want to expose myself to legal penalties, though I have been careful to document in case it goes there.

Comment: You said this project cannot be finished. If that is the case, then you have the choice between leaving now and having failed, leaving in ten years time and having failed, or never leaving and dying of old age in the contract. Your choice. I recommend first getting a lawyer who examines your contract and tells you the cost of leaving, and then getting out like a shot. BTW. I really hope for you that you have set up some limited liability company, That' what LLC's are for, you let them go down the drain when things go really badly and start another one.

Comment: @wormwood: A single project is not a pattern.  Also, I'd hazard a guess that every professional has worked on failed projects.  Those are the ones you learn the most from.

Comment: "The quality of my work and reputation are important to me." This approval-seeking is going to get you nowhere. You need to learn to say 'No'. You need to create some boundaries for yourself. You need to stop this project now! Don't let your pride get in the way. And yes, you need to consult a lawyer. I suspect that the "mass deletion of my work without explanation..." should be more than enough to be considered a breach of contract, but then again I am not a lawyer and I do not even know if you can prove that your client is the one who deleted that. Are you even using version control?

Comment: Yes, I am using version control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try to have a frank discussion about the situation.**

Basically, you want a meeting where you can say "Let's be honest; this hasn't been working. Can we agree to make some changes so that we can achieve success?"

Use this meeting to explain clearly and dispassionately how things have been different from your expectations, and why you are finding it impossible to deliver what they want in this situation.

But also be ready to listen about how your work has not been meeting their expectations.  And if you can admit up front that some of the fault is yours (your question seems to imply this when you mention "my inexperience"), this will go a long way.

**Hopefully you can mutually agree on some concrete change to achieve success.**

A key part of this would be a document describing clearly what the remaining work you have to deliver is, and any requirements about "tools, standards, and/or methods" and so on, that might be in dispute.

This should be a *mutually agreed* document, not something they simply give to you and say here it is.

Of course this is something that should have been in the contract; the fact that it is not reduces your leverage.  However, you still need to agree with them what you have to do going forward, and this should be written down.  The company does have some incentive to come to an agreement with you: like you, they probably realize that the project currently is not on a path to success, and this is not good for them either.  A compromise on achieving something is better than them getting nothing out of a failed project.

Also try to agree on a regular way to monitor how things are going at a high level.

**Be willing to eat a large scope change, as long as there is real change in how the project works going forward.**

At this point, the path to success is probably going to be a lot more time than your original contract pays you for.  But at this point in your career, you should probably just stick it out and complete the project for the original price (if reasonably possible).  Unless you have other work opportunities immediately available, turning this into a success is probably the most valuable way you could use your time right now.

Of course you shouldn't put up with scope changes from the original contract, but the contract wasn't clear about this (a lesson you have learned) so you should just do your best to fulfill that contract.

Only do this if there is real change to the project, though.  If it continues to be dysfunctional, you will be just throwing more effort and time into a failed enterprise.

**If you can't agree on a better way forward, aim for mutual agreement to end the contract.**

Perhaps they aren't interested in changing things, or they just blame you for everything.  Or perhaps they agree to do things differently, but the same old pattern emerges again.  If so I would try for "this isn't working out; let's both just walk away from this".  You would stop the work, keep the money you have been paid so far, and not seek the rest of your payment.

It's not clear what exactly the contract stipulates about the work ending before the project is completed, but that is irrelevant if both parties mutually agree on a solution.  And no one would really benefit from taking this to court, so it's likely that such an agreement could be arrived at.

It's possible that they will not be interested, and instead threaten legal action.  If so, contact a lawyer.  But there's a good chance it will be in everyone's interest to resolve things amicably.

Comment: That's a good answer and one I'll be trying. I'm not terribly optimistic at this point, because I've made several overtures and/or requests for clarification that were received poorly, but if I try to get everything out in the open, maybe I can get past that initial response. And if nothing else, it is important to at least make the effort to resolve things in a professional fashion.

Comment: Just want to comment again--this is just an excellent answer. I can't tell you how much I appreciate the advice in it.

Answer (score 2):

You, my friend, are on a [Death March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(project_management)) project.  It's sounding like you took on some fixed-price work without including tangible project milestones along the way, and now your money is tied up based on intangible success measures.  The best you can do is to try to work toward the next "checkpoint" (finished unit-of-work) and get your butt out of there with a check.  Then, jump over to the [Freelancing StackExchange](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) and learn how others are dealing with this.  There's a huge body of knowledge available on do's and do-not's for dealing with contract work.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for referring me to the Freelancing forum. I can see I'll be reading a ton of it in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a few "clues" in your comment, I sense that your client may have a very different perspective of your work. That they *are not* satisfied, and that they are withholding payment because they feel that the contract is being breached (by you).

Even if, in fact, there is no breach, they can *say* that there is one, especially if the project, having gone so-far over "time," has also gone over "budget," and *employees* (by law) must be paid first.

You, possibly accompanied by your attorney, need to immediately discuss the present state of the contract, and of the project in general.

The harsh realities of IT projects, especially as experienced by a true *contractor,* send many "former academics" scurrying right back to the cloistered halls that they had left.